# Migrate system to larger drive

Tags: disk-management

I had a small hard drive  (13 GB) which was too small. I added another (160 GB) but the apps don't seem to use it. File Manager appears to but no other apps, specifically, the Update Manager won't use it. I need to use this new drive because there is too little space to download the latest updates to the kernel, etc. So,

1. How do I tell update manager to use this drive?
2. How do I get other apps to use it?

Running Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it.

To solve you problem you need to migrate your root partition (13 GB) to a bigger partition on your new 160 GB drive.

Try also alternative howto's like [Migrate from HDD to SSD](http://www.sesser.eu/howtos/hdd2ssd.php) or similar.

- Partition your drive about 40 GB for system, everything else data.
- take care where you save your data, especially big files like movies, they should be stored on data, not on root.
- move your root partition to the new drive with rsync
- mount your drive from a rescure disk and chroot to it.
- install grub on the new drive's MBR.
- remove your old disk
- reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd keep your `/` partition on your current 16GB drive. If you use a swap file, I'd put that there as well. Then use the 160GB drive as your `/home`. No current Ubuntu installation is likely to use more than 10GB for system files. It's user files (video, music, etc. that take up most of your space.

The best time to do this is when you're installing or re-installing from scratch. [There are several tutorials online that explain how to manually partition your file system while installing](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installseparatehome). Just backup your data first, then copy it all from your backup location back to your new `~/`. Don't forget any hidden files.

[It's possible to do this with an existing install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving), but it's more work, and there's a chance of a catastrophic failure which would wipe your user data, so backup your data first.

Better still, backup your data every week, just in case.